# "Reidemeister moves" for self-intersecting loops

Tags: knot-theory

Reidemeister showed that just three basic *moves* (which manipulated crossings) were needed to test whether two knots were equivalent or "ambient isotopic."  Suppose we expand the class of topological objects to permit self-intersection, as here:

[image: self-intersecting]

The notion of ambient isotopy applies to such objects.  What is the smallest class of *moves* that guarantees one can transform such an object into any other ambient isotopic object?

I suspect the Reidemeister moves need be augmented by fairly trivial moves passing segments *above* or *beneath* the intersected crossing, but how would one prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These objects are called **spatial graphs**.  A set of Reidemeister moves for them was found by Kauffman; see

L H Kauffman, Invariants of graphs in three-space, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 311 (1989) 697–710.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much for the reference.  (accept) . Indeed, the additional *moves* are fairly straightforward (including the "twist" of segments at an intersection).